# Cannot connect to mssql database using Django (Mac OS)

Tags: sql-server, django, macos

My mssql database is inside the docker container. When trying to connect to the database using azure data studio I don't get any errors, whereas when I'm trying to connect to the db using Django I get the following **error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 486, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 220, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 230, in _cursor
    conn = super()._cursor()
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Users/aleksandr/Desktop/teplo/teplo_back/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 326, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(connstr,
django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

**Django db configuration:**

```
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 1433,
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_pwd',
         'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        }
    }
}
```

**Installed packages:**

```
Django==3.2.9
mssql-django==1.0
pyodbc==4.0.30
```

Comment: Did you forward the port 1433 on your container to localhost? What happens when you try to connect to the container directly (so no localhost but whatever IP your container has)?

Comment: Also, maybe this issue helps you (provided you have influence over the container config)? https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/610

Comment: When I specify the IP address of the container I get the "login timeout expired" error:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually managed to solve the problem. The trouble was linked to SSL.

First, you have to open the folder `/usr/local/opt`. There, you can find the `openssl@1.1` folder. You have to grab all of the files from there and put them into the `openssl` folder.

After that, I managed to run Django server successfully.

Comment: Good that you found it and even better that you took the time to reply the answer to future people browsing the same questions.